ClassNotFoundException in WildFly when using runtime-name argument for deployment
I need to use the --runtime-name argument when deploying an application for giving a stable name for HA singleton deployment which uses the runtime-name (deployment) for distinguishing singleton deployments. The default - the WAR's filename - does not work because our WAR filename contains a version number. A new version would thus form a different singleton.
So I deploy (WildFly 27.0.1) using a command-line like ./jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="deploy MyApp-1.0.0.war --name=MyApp-1.0.0.war --runtime-name=MyApp --force"
When using the filename as runtime-name (or omitting the --runtime-name arg), the application loads without issue.
But when I use a runtime-name that is different from the filename of the WAR file, the application does not start because none of the included classes is found. I.e., I get ClassNotFoundException for any class contained in the WAR.
Am I doing something wrong?
2024-05-28 15:15:11,201 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2)  MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit.MyApp.POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.MyApp.POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "MyApp"
        at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.my.app.server.reports.control.TabControl from [Module "deployment.MyApp" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:260)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:89)
        at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.my.app.server.reports.control.TabControl from [Module "deployment.MyApp" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:200)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:258)
        ... 10 more



A ClassNotFoundException typically means the class cannot be found in the deployment so I would check that first. Also for the runtime-name you do need to use an extension like .war. In your case --runtime-name=MyApp.war.

As I explained above, the deployment loads without any issue when using its file-name, so the class is contained. Also, I've tried using a runtime-name with .war suffix which does not make a difference. The deployment fails with ClassNotFound unless I use the runtime-name identical to the file-name.
It seems to me like when using runtime-name, WildFly uses wrong Class-Loader.

Sorry, for the confusion. There was another issue with my .war test.
Yes, it seems like adding .war suffix to the name makes a difference.
Thanks for your help.
